# long query takes a long time

Tags: mysql

I have a rather complex query in mysql 5.1.73-community. It involves joining tables and view at the same time.

Here is the query:

```
VIEW v_summary AS (
select (--some 35 columns fro tabel A B C D F)
from (((((ht_counters_sales_items_b a
       left join ht_counters_sales_b b
         on ((a.tcsi_tcs_id = b.tcs_id)))
      left join ht_counters_trans_b c
        on ((b.tcs_no = c.tct_ref_no)))
     left join **VIEW_counters_activities** d
       on ((c.tct_tca_id = d.tca_id)))
    left join m_items e
      on ((e.mi_id = a.tcsi_mi_id)))
   left join m_items_categories f
     on ((f.mic_id = e.mi_mic_id)))
where ((c.tct_voided = '0')
       and (a.tcsi_voided = '0'))
group by a.tcsi_id)$$
```

Table A : index (tcsi_id) PRIMARY

Table B : index (tcs_id) PRIMARY

Table C : index (tct_id) PRIMARY

Table E : index (mi_id) PRIMARY, (mi_code,mi_id),(mi_name,mi_id),
(mi_mic_id,mi_id),(mi_mu_id,mi_id),(mi_mu_id,mi_mic_id,mi_id),(mi_id,mi_mu_id,mi_mic_id)

Tabel F : index (mic_id) PRIMARY, (mic_mu_id),(mic_type),(mic_lft,mic_rgt,miclvl),(mic_name,mic_id)

Another view that is involved in the above view is as follows :

```
VIEW **VIEW_counters_activities** AS(SELECT
  SUM((CASE g.tct_ref_journal WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN (g.tct_ref_value - g.tct_ref_voided) WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN ((0 - g.tct_ref_value) + g.tct_ref_voided) ELSE 0 END)) AS tca_close_cash,
  a.tca_id            AS tca_id,
  a.tca_open_date     AS tca_date,
  a.tca_open_date     AS tca_open_date,
  a.tca_open_date     AS tca_open_time,
  a.tca_close_date    AS tca_close_date,
  a.tca_close_date    AS tca_close_time,
  a.tca_mc_id         AS tca_mc_id,
  a.tca_mst_id        AS tca_mst_id,
  a.tca_state         AS tca_state,
  a.tca_user_id       AS tca_user_id,
  a.tca_open_cash     AS tca_open_cash,
  a.tca_mutation_cash AS tca_mutation_cash,
  a.tca_controller    AS tca_controller,
  a.tca_coordinator   AS tca_coordinator,
  b.mhr_scd_name      AS tca_mhr_scd_name,
  c.fullname          AS tca_user_name,
  d.fullname          AS tca_controller_name,
  e.fullname          AS tca_coordinator_name,
  f.mc_name           AS tca_mc_name,
  f.mc_ip_address     AS tca_mc_ip_address,
  f.mc_mcp_type       AS tca_mc_mcp_type,
  f.mc_mcp_name       AS tca_mc_mcp_name,
  f.mc_ml_id          AS tca_mc_ml_id,
  f.mc_ml_type        AS tca_mc_ml_type,
  f.mc_ml_name        AS tca_mc_ml_name,
  h.mpr_name          AS tca_receipt_printer_name,
  h.mpr_ip_address    AS tca_receipt_printer_address,
  i.mpr_name          AS tca_report_printer_name,
  i.mpr_ip_address    AS tca_report_printer_address,
  j.mst_name          AS tca_mst_name
FROM (((((((((ht_counters_activities_b a
           LEFT JOIN m_hr_schedules b
             ON ((a.tca_mhr_scd_id = b.mhr_scd_id)))
          LEFT JOIN v_users c
            ON ((a.tca_user_id = c.id)))
         LEFT JOIN v_users d
           ON ((a.tca_controller = d.id)))
        LEFT JOIN v_users e
          ON ((a.tca_coordinator = e.id)))
       LEFT JOIN v_counters f
         ON ((a.tca_mc_id = f.mc_id)))
      LEFT JOIN ht_counters_trans_b g
        ON (((a.tca_id = g.tct_tca_id)
             AND (g.tct_ref_mpm_type = 'CASH')
             AND (g.tct_voided = 0))))
     LEFT JOIN m_printers h
       ON ((f.mc_receipt_printer = h.mpr_id)))
    LEFT JOIN m_printers i
      ON ((f.mc_report_printer = i.mpr_id)))
   LEFT JOIN m_sales_types j
     ON ((a.tca_mst_id = j.mst_id)))
GROUP BY a.tca_id))
```

As i am writing this, the query `SELECT * FROM v_summary WHERE MONTH(trx_date) = 7` has run for 70 minutes and still counting.

How can i make it faster ?

All of the tables are INNODB.

MySQL settings:

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_size 2147483648
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
join_buffer_size    131072
key_buffer_size 57671680
myisam_sort_buffer_size 130023424
net_buffer_length   16384
preload_buffer_size 32768
read_buffer_size    65536
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_buffer_result   OFF
max_heap_table_size 64M
tmp_table_size 124M
SET PROFILING = ON
```

Comment: IMHO , Long query take long time,short query take short time.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?

Answer (score 1):

Several optimizations tips:

1. **Left joins to inner joins**

   You can probably simplify the views a little bit by converting some `LEFT JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s. For instance, for the first view, you have a `WHERE` clause of `c.tct_voided = 0`, this will make the involved join behave like an inner join instead of a left one. If the row on `c` were not found, the `c.tct_voided = 0` won't be true, and won't be returned. Explicitly changing the `LEFT` to `INNER` will help the database some. That might *improve a little bit* the execution time.

   Some of the other `LEFT JOIN`s might already by `INNER JOIN`s just because of referential integrity, or the nature of your data. If you know for sure that there's always a corresponding row on your right table, change the `LEFT` to `INNER`.
2. **Indexes on the expressions that are part of a join**

   If you have a join condition that is

   ```
   (ht_counters_sales_items_b a
   LEFT JOIN ht_counters_sales_b b
       ON a.tcsi_tcs_id = b.tcs_id)
   LEFT JOIN ht_counters_trans_b c
       ON b.tcs_no = c.tct_ref_no
   ```

   You are likely to gain a lot of speed if there is a `KEY(tct_ref_no)` on table `ht_counters_trans_b`. The same might apply to `KEY(tcs_no)` on table `ht_counters_sales_b` (if the `LEFT JOIN` were an `INNER JOIN` and MySQL would decide to process it right-to-left, instead of left-to-right).
3. **Not forcing order of join execution**

   In some occasions (and this really needs to be tested, I don't know how good is MySQL at it), *not* putting any `(...)` on the `JOIN`s gives the database more freedom to process them in the order it seems more appropriate. This is normally true for `INNER JOIN`s, but shouldn't have a significant effect on `LEFT JOIN`s.
4. **`WHERE` clauses**

   ```
   SELECT * FROM v_summary WHERE MONTH(trx_date) = 7
   ```

   If you want to look for all the data for *July this year*, you're more likely to get a much faster result if `trx_date` is indexed, and you write your query like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM v_summary WHERE trx_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
   ```

   This will allow the database to use the index. Having a function applied to the column will prevent it from using it, and force a sequential scan on all the results. And that's not what you want.